# Boost [Windows] - is it normal to be forced to link against extra libraries?

Tags: c++, boost, build, boost-asio

I'm trying to use Boost.Asio for network programming on Windows 10, but compiling like this:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -IC:\Boost\boost_1_71_0
```

causes the linker to complain:

> (...) undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'

I know the problem can be resolved simply by appending `-lWs2_32` to the build command, but **is this really the proper way** of doing things? Directly linking against a particular "external" binary?

Pardon me if this question seems weird or unnecessary, but it feels wrong to be forced to keep track on top of which libraries is Boost implemented (even though it's such an obvious one).

Comment: Have you tried with MSVC ? Do you still need the flag ?

Comment: `Ws2_32.lib` is a stub library that will use the current platform `Ws2_32.dll` at runtime.

Comment: You have to link with (and *ship with your application*) everything your program uses (even transitively), yes. Most build systems manage to hide the nitty gritty details from you most of the time, but that doesn't mean they are not there..

Comment: Looking further it should have been done automatically see `BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEFAULT_LINKED_LIBS` in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html  or not just noticed you are using `g++` not `MSVC`

Comment: @JesperJuhl: That's obviously untrue. You don't ship the OS with your application, and WS2_32.dll is part of the OS. You _do_ have to link against it, though.

Comment: @MSalters Right. You don't have to ship things that are part of the core OS. I was thinking along the lines of how people usually always forget that they have to ship the compiler runtime libraries and other non-core-OS stuff that they link with but don't think about.

Comment: @Xatyrian I tried, but instead it complains about not being able to link against boost_date_time. I have no experience in compiling with MSCV though, so I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: However I did overlook what @RichardCritten pointed out - the docs state that only MSVC and Borland can automagically link against specific libraries. So I guess that's the answer to my question.